# <p:dialog> não funciona

Tags: java, primefaces, dialog

Estou seguindo o exemplo do showcase porém não funciona. Era pra aparecer um icone e depois que eu clicasse nesse ícone ele abria o Dialog porém quando abro a página já fica desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código:

```
<body>
    <h:form>            
    <h:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" title="login">
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/login.png" />
    </h:outputLink>

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

    <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userLoginView.username}" required="true" label="username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{userLoginView.password}" required="true" label="password" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" actionListener="#{userLoginView.login}"
                                 oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
</body>
```